# Propositional Logic: the negation and the Contrapositive of the following affirmation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Help me please. ($p\Rightarrow q$)

What is the reciprocal, the negation and the Contrapositive of the following affirmation

$$
\text{A Lannister always pays his debts}
$$
the negation is: There was one case where a Lannister did not pay,

reciprocal($q\Rightarrow p$) is: If you pay your debts you are a lannister? this is true?

Contrapositive ($\sim q\Rightarrow \sim p$).If you do not pay your debts you are not a lannister? this is true?

help me please.

Comment: welcome to maths stackexchange. kindly include your thoughts and  attempts in your posts if possible.

Comment: the negation is: There was one case where a Lannister did not pay,   More reciprocal and    Contrapositive.?

Comment: @ros, Well, what do "reciprocal" and "contrapositive" mean *to you*?  ( Your negation is okay, by the way. I'd go with "Some Lannisters have depts that they will not pay.")

Comment: reciprocal($q\Rightarrow p$) is: If you pay your debts you are a lannister? this is true?

Contrapositive ($\sim q\Rightarrow \sim p$).If you do not pay your debts you are not a lannister? this is true?

help me please.

Comment: For the *negation* you have to use both predicate and propositional logic. The first part needs predicate logic in order to "negate" the leading quantifier. The negation of $\forall x$ is $\exists x \lnot$. For the propositional part, the negation of $p \to q$ is $p \land \lnot q$.

Comment: Thus: "A Lannister always pays his debts" must be: "for every $x$, if $x$ is a Lannister, then $x$ always pays his debts". Thus, the negation must be: "exists $x$ such that, $x$ is a Lannister and $x$ does **not** pay his debts".

Comment: For the *contrapositive*, you are right: the contrapositive of $p \to q$ is $\lnot q \to \lnot p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial statement SEEMS to be a sentence $$\forall X\left (X\mbox{ is a Lannister}\Longrightarrow X\mbox{ pays his debts}\right ) $$
Read this as: For every $X$, if $X$ is a Lannister, then $X$ pays his debts.
To negate the statement, it becomes
$$\exists X: X\mbox{ is a Lannister and } X\mbox{ does not pay his debts} $$
Read this as: There exists an $X$ such that $X$ is a Lannister and $X$ doesn't pay his debts.

To form the contrapositive, which is logically Equivalent to the initial statement:
$$\forall X\left (X \mbox{ does not pay his debts}\Longrightarrow X\mbox{ is not a Lannister}\right ) $$
Read this as: For every $X$, if $X$ does not pay his debts, then $X$ is not a Lannister.

There's the part "..**always** pays his debts".
$$\forall X,\forall Y\left (X\mbox{ is a Lannister and }Y\mbox{ is a debt of $X$}\Longrightarrow X\mbox{ pays } Y\right ) $$
The negation becomes:
$$\exists X,\exists Y : X\mbox{ is a Lannister and } Y\mbox{ is a debt of }X\mbox{ and } X\mbox{ does not pay }Y$$
The contrapositive becomes:
$$\forall X,\forall Y\left (X\mbox{ does not pay }Y\Longrightarrow X\mbox{ is not a Lannister or }Y\mbox{ is not a debt of }X \right ) $$
I'm not sure if it's necessary to make the distinction.

Edit: Just to be on the safe side, I would go with the second option. I'm wary of potential wordplay in "A Lannister always pays his debts" and I'm not an English expert.